# How can I stop Eclipse popup?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a new project in eclipse . If the created project has any error like `classpath resolvation , code rror` java builder throws this message in a popup .

```
`Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'zmedia'.
java.lang.NullPointerException`
```

How can I prevent opening this popup in eclipse? . I

Comment: Can you check .metadata/.log in your workspace? It should have the exception stack trace that may help you fix the project metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is not about errors in your project, but instead this is an error in the Eclipse Java tooling itself.